# C# Using for loops to process multiple elements in the WinForm Environment

Tags: c#, loops, dynamic, controls, element

I am pretty new to C#, I have been searching for an hour or so now for what I need and can't find it. I am trying to look at the contents of 32 different text box's using for loops.
The code I have at the moment is:

```
    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ElementString;
        Control ElementControl;
        double Num;
        Boolean errorMsg = false;

        for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
            for (int y = 1; y <= 4; y++)
            {
                ElementString = "txtA" + x.ToString() + y.ToString();
                ElementControl = this.Controls[ElementString];
                ElementString = ElementControl.Text.Trim();

                if (!double.TryParse(ElementString, out Num))
                {
                    errorMsg = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

        if (errorMsg)
            MessageBox.Show("Error Processing Input Matricies, invalid entries");
    }
```

Ok changing this part, sorry for not putting more information, but hopefully this will help.

The program crashes when the button is clicked.  It crashes when running the line:

```
ElementString = ElementControl.Text.Trim();
```

And gives the error message:
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Thank you

Comment: "it doesnt work" (sic) is *never* enough information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is check if `ElementControl` is null.  Do that right before you call the line that is throwing the exception.

Another way to do this would be to search for all of the `TextBox` controls in your container and check them that way.  You can use the following to do that:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        // Do whatever you want to do with your textbox.
    }
}
```

That is much more dynamic than trying to call retrieve the controls by name.

Answer (score 0):

put an if statement around the part where it crashes:

```
if(ElementControl != null)
{
  ElementString = ElementControl.Text.Trim();
}
else
{
 //Handle error if element control is null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My code did work it was just the fact that the textbox's where inside a groupbox.